# State updates incorrectly in child component

Tags: reactjs

I have a product list component which looks like a todo list - rows of products. I have two loaders:

- First is a spinner loader. I want to show it on page loading when there's no data. Just spinner and nothing else because data is fetching from server.
- Second is a area loader. It is semi-transparent overlay over product list with text Updating... I want to show it when product is updated.

I managed to do that but there's a problem. If I update a product data the product list is not updated. For example I update a product --> product list with old data --> open product form agan and close it then product list updated. How can I fix that?

**Products component**

```
const Products: React.FC = () => {
  const [isFormOpen, setIsFormOpen] = useState(false);
  const { products } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.product);
  const { brand, category, product } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state);
  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();

  const hasCategories = category.categories.length > 0;
  const hasProducts = products.length > 0;
  const hasBrands = brand.brands.length > 0;
  const productsIsLoading = !hasProducts && product.isLoading;
  const isProductListVisible = hasCategories && hasProducts && hasBrands && !isFormOpen;

  const openForm = () => {
    setIsFormOpen(true);
  };

  const closeForm = () => {
    setIsFormOpen(false);
    dispatch(removeSelectedProduct());
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Actions
        title={'Products'}
        onAction={openForm}
        actionBtnText={'Add product'}
        isOpen={isFormOpen}
        isDisabled={!hasCategories || !hasBrands}
      />

      <Content>
        <>
          {productsIsLoading && <Loader />}

          {isProductListVisible && (
            <ProductsList
              products={products}
              onOpen={openForm}
              isLoading={product.isLoading}
              categories={category.categories}
              brands={brand.brands}
            />
          )}
          {isFormOpen && <ProductForm onClose={closeForm} categories={category.categories} brands={brand.brands} />}
        </>
      </Content>
    </>
  );
};
```

**ProductList component (child)**
In child component I set products prop to state productList and render all products rows with data from productList because child has select filters for products and has lots of logic because of that filters.

```
const ProductsList: React.FC<IProductsListProps> = ({ products, onOpen, isLoading, categories, brands }) => {
  const [productList, setProductList] = useState<Product[]>(products);

  return (
    <Card fullWidth>
      <>
        {isLoading && <AreaLoader />}
        <table>// ...some code</table>
      </>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default ProductsList;
```

I can fix the problem with useEffect in child component. But it seems to me that there are extra re-renders which are not good in general.

```
 // if add to ProductList the problem is gone. Is it okay fix?
 useEffect(()=> {
    setProductList(products)
  }, [products])
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, then you have "products" in redux state. Next, you pass "products" to the local state of the component. Why do you need this? Abandon the use of local state and work only with redux and then you will not need useEffect.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I use local state because there are two select filters in child component and around 100 lines of code so that filters worked as needed (two-way binding between filters). And I think Redux store is not the right place for filters logic.

Comment: I usually make 2 states. One source, and the second for filters, searches, and etc. But here you already need to look at what is more convenient for you, of course. Regarding re-renderers, you can enable the "Highlight updates when components render" option in react devtools and see what happens there. Maybe everything is fine and there is nothing to worry about. Also, do not forget about memo, useCallback...